# mongorestore not working after mongodump

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I am using a mongodb with `version:2.4.14`
I have used the below command to dump a database named masters
 `mongodump -d masters -o /var/www/html/test/dbbackup`
It runs successfully and in dbbackup folder i got so many files with the collection name with type `.json` and `.bson`
Now when I am trying to restore the db using the following command
`mongorestore -d testdatabase1 /var/www/html/test/dbbackup/`
I am getting the following error:
`ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single database
ERROR: when specifying a db name with --db`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `original database name` in the path as :

```
mongorestore -d testdatabase1 /var/www/html/test/dbbackup/masters
```